# Head Script output explanation

Tags: shell-script, files, input, head

So this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
head >/dev/null;
head;
```

almost always gives the same output when called with sequential numbers (e.g. seq 10000 | ./sscript)

OUPUT:

```
     //blank line
1861
1862
1863
1864
1865
1866
1867
1868
1869
```

I straced it with `strace seq 10000 | ./sscript` but wasn't able to explain to myself, where exactly these numbers come from. At the end of strace:

```
write(1, "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "1\n1042\n1043\n1044\n1045\n1046\n1047\n"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "\n1861\n1862\n1863\n1864\n1865\n1866\n1"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "2680\n2681\n2682\n2683\n2684\n2685\n26"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "499\n3500\n3501\n3502\n3503\n3504\n350"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "18\n4319\n4320\n4321\n4322\n4323\n4324"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "7\n5138\n5139\n5140\n5141\n5142\n5143\n"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "\n5957\n5958\n5959\n5960\n5961\n5962\n5"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "6776\n6777\n6778\n6779\n6780\n6781\n67"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "595\n7596\n7597\n7598\n7599\n7600\n760"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "14\n8415\n8416\n8417\n8418\n8419\n8420"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "3\n9234\n9235\n9236\n9237\n9238\n9239\n"..., 3838) = 3838
```

Why only the 3rd `write` is returned (sometimes only the 2nd)?

Actually only the first 10 of the returned line (3rd or 2nd write) are printed because of the second `head` in script but still lost.

Comment: you should try it w/ a regular file. `seq 10000 >/tmp/nums; yourscript </tmp/nums`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`head` prints 10 lines by default, but it reads in as much input as it can while doing so - note that GNU `head` has options which require it to know how many lines there are in the file in total, so reading in as much as it can is not wrong.

`head` reads in as much as it can to fill its buffer, which seems to be 8192 bytes:

```
~ seq 10000 | strace -fe read ./foo.sh
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260e\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
...
Process 17610 attached
...
[pid 17610] read(0, "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14"..., 8192) = 8192
...
[pid 17611] read(0, "\n1861\n1862\n1863\n1864\n1865\n1866\n1"..., 8192) = 8192
...
```

Since the first two writes are 4096 bytes each, they can be consumed by the first `head`.

This depends on timing. If `seq` only managed to get one `write` away by the time the first `head` printed 10 lines and quit, then the second `write` will be taken by the second `head`.

The [comment from mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv) is illuminating:

> you should try it w/ a regular file.
>
> ```
> seq 10000 >/tmp/nums; yourscript </tmp/nums
> ```

The reason this behaves as you would expect is that `head` tries to reposition the current reading point to the line after the ones it had output using [`lseek()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lseek.3posix). This works for normal files, redirected files, etc., but doesn't work for pipes:

```
The lseek() function shall fail if:

...

ESPIPE The fildes argument is associated with a pipe, FIFO, or socket.
```

As can be seen using `strace`:

```
~ seq 10000 | strace -fe lseek ./foo.sh
...
Process 18561 attached
[pid 18561] lseek(0, -8171, SEEK_CUR)   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
[pid 18561] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=18561, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Process 18562 attached
[pid 18562] lseek(0, -8146, SEEK_CUR)   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
...
```

Comment: very nice edit... cant upvote it again, though. sometimes it can be useful to do stuff like: `set %b%s; man man | grep -n '' >/tmp/regfile; while IFS=: read -r i ln; do set "$@" "\nline# $i\n\t" "$ln"; head -n "$((i-1))" >&3; done </tmp/regfile 3>/dev/null; printf "$@" \\n`. `dd` is good for that as well with `{ dd bs=$skip_size skip=$skip_multiplier count=0; $utility_to_read_at_new_offset; } <regfile` because you can instantly seek to arbitrary byte offsets in input. and GNU `grep` can do the same stuff w/ `-m$count`. *(p.s. - i know it looks funny in the comments, but run it: its cool)*